# VS Code "Include file not found in include path."

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, include-path

First of all, I know this issue has been answered a bunch of times already, but the answer (the same one every time) doesn't work for me still..

I get the infamous "Include file not found in include path" when trying to include iostream in a simple hello world c++ program. I then include the path to my MinGW include folder as follows:

```
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
```

Yet, I still get the same error. This is, for what I've found, the only solution to this problem. It's really frustrating that VS Code just doesn't seem to recognize the path.

Any advice is helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Did you check to make sure you don't need escape characters in your string C://MinGW//lib//gcc etc.

Comment: I've tried "\\", "\", "/" & "//".. nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you're looking at it from the start of the project.  I would go to the extension (C++ my guess) and see how to implement it. If this doesn't work for you I would check your path.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Answer (score 0):

I met the same trouble with you.

Maybe you could try to set "brose"-"path" like this.

```
{
    "name": "Win32",
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceRoot}",
        "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++"
    ],
    "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE"
    ],
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/include/c++"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
        "databaseFilename": ""
    }
}
```

Wish this could help you.